# Why does the status bar look so tall when I add a navigation controller?

Tags: ios

I used to set the window's view with `[self.window setRootViewController:myViewController]` where `myViewController` was just an ordinary view controller. The status bar looked normal. Then I added a navigation controller. I used:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:NO];
NSLog(@"height of status bar is %d", [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height);
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

The log prints "height of status bar is 20".

Yet the status bar look super tall:

[image]

Comment: I don't see the navigation bar in the screenshot you took, is it possible it's the same as the status bar's color( or transparent) and the status bar IS actually 20px?

Comment: Are you targeting iOS7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the navigationbar with status bar. As both are of same color so it seems you that status bar height is larger.

Change Color of Navigationbar and then check :

```
[your_navController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```